# is Module position vacant or not

Tags: joomla

i have created a New position"sidebar-left" is Yootheme's Nano 3 Template.

Yootheme allows only one side sidebars, either left or right.

so i keep it to sidebar-right and create new position Sidebar-left. because i need both side sidebars.

Now my problem:
i kept the width of main content areas to 65%, so when there is no sidebars modules exist in the page, my main content still uses 65% width of page. i need it to cover more are than this because now sidebar modules are not linked.

so i want to know what is the way to knw weather module position is vacant or not. so that i can apply conditions.

or is there any other you people can suggest?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If I rightly remember, new Yootheme templates allowed you to have a left and right sidebar. You have to set it up in the parameters. But regarding the main issue, this is not the place to be asking support for a commercial template. Post a comment on the Yootheme website as the Yootheme developers are there to assist you

Comment: Thanks Loader for your reply...
but i got the solution.. 
if you say, i can post the solution...

Comment: Indeed, please post the answer and accept it so people know it has bren solved and to help thos who may have the same problem in future ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
first you need to count number of module in the mentioned position

if($this['widgets']->count('sidebar-left') == 0)

if this satisfies then, 
{
        ?>

```
            <?php if ($this['config']->get('system_output', true)) : ?>
            <main class="**tm-content1**">

                <?php if ($this['widgets']->count('breadcrumbs')) : ?>
                <?php echo $this['widgets']->render('breadcrumbs'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php echo $this['template']->render('content'); ?>

            </main>
```

then we need to render the main content output as done above.
we cannot dynamically change the css with php so we need to create new css class with the larger width and put in if case, and then in 
else case put the same code to make it run with the main css class.